# Rails 3 w/ Devise: How to set two separate homepages based on whether the user is authenticated or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-routing

I am using Rails 3 and Devise to create an app where users arrive to the website and are shown a homepage containing a login and a signup form. This page has its own controller ("homepage") so it's route is

```
root :to => "homepage#index"
```

I want to display a different homepage if the users are already logged in. This would account to having the root point to

```
root :to => "dashboard#index"
```

Is there a way to have a conditional route in routes.rb, that would allow me to check whether the user is authenticated before routing them to one of those homepages?

I tried using the following code but if I'm not logged in, devise asks me to log in, so clearly only the first route works.

```
authenticate :user do
  root :to => "dashboard#index"
end
  root :to => "homepage#index"
```

Also, I want the url to point to www.example.com in both cases, so that www.example.com/dashboard/index and www.example.com/homepage/index never appear in the browser.

Thanks a million !!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this, it's specific to Warden/Devise though.

```
root to: "dashboard#index", constraints: lambda { |r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }
root to: "homepage#index"
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Bradley, this was killing me :)

Comment: I do the same, but both logged in user and not logged in user used the dashboard#index

Comment: Warning: This doesn't work with Rails 4, you get an error saying: `Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'`

Comment: Edit: When using Rails 4 you can just add a different name for the route and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

In your HomeController:

```
def index
  if !user_signed_in?
    redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @negarnil. The thing is, I tried this option but it does not rewrite the url. I want www.example.com to point to both pages so that www.example.com/dashboard/index is never shown

Comment: Try render :action => 'dashboard.html.erb. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#wrapping-it-up

Answer (score 2):

(Exact same question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233831/930038. Adding the answer here too for others' reference.)

In your `routes.rb` :

```
authenticated do
  root :to => 'dashboard#index'
end

root :to => 'homepage#index'
```

This will ensure that `root_url` for all authenticated users is `dashboard#index`

For your reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1147

Comment: In Rails 4 this does not work. You have to rename one of the two Routes. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19090936/1836143).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct answer with rails 4

```
root to: 'dashboard#index', constraints: -> (r) { r.env["warden"].authenticate? },
         as: :authenticated_root
root to: 'homepage#index'
```

I tried to add this to / edit the accepted answer but it's too much of an edit to be accepted apparently. Anyway, vote for the accepted answer (from Bradley), it helped me come up with this one :)