# Different page for logged in user and not logged in user at root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show different root page for users in Rails.

I defined the root:

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

And the welcome control:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

end
```

Currently it is ok for logged in users, but the not logged in users redirected to /users/sign_in

I want to show static root page and not redirect.

Comment: Remove your before_filter and add your logic into the index method to determine what to display based on whether they are logged in.  Are you using devise?

Comment: @MarcTalbot yes, is it possible implement in routes.rb ?

Comment: This exact question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888289/rails-3-w-devise-how-to-set-two-separate-homepages-based-on-whether-the-user-i/8888513#8888513

Comment: That did not worked. @Bradley

Comment: Your routes.rb file has no way of knowing whether your user is authenticated or not.  What is not working about putting the logic in the index method of the controller?

Comment: If you are using warden, which is what devise is built on, you do actually have access to whether the user is logged in or not in the routes file through env['warden'].

Answer (score 25):

The answer, suggested by Puneet Goyal will not work in Rails 4. See [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17298414). The solution is to use an alias for one of the two routes like this:

```
authenticated do
  root :to => 'welcome#index', as: :authenticated
end

root :to => 'home#static_page'
```

Comment: Jose Valim discusses this solution in a Devise issue [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17298414)

Answer (score 2):

This answer should work. This was posted on the page Bradley linked.

Put this in your Welcome controller.

```
def index
  if authenticate_user?
    redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index'
  else
    redirect_to '/public/example_html_file.html'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `routes.rb` :

```
authenticated do
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end

root :to => 'home#static_page'
```

This will ensure that `root_url` for all authenticated users is `welcome#index`

For your reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1147

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 4 anymore, try: authenticated :user do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end
  root to: 'landing_page#index', as: :public_root